# What's the most effective way to get wifi working?

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I'm using Ubuntu since a few years and I remember having trouble to connect to the internet with wifi on almost every version. I have been using laptop, desktop pc, with wifi dongle or with built in wifi card.

My question is : What is the safer (and by safer I mean with the best result) way to use wireless internet connection on Ubuntu ? I hope to have answers and different opinions from long-time user with experience on different pc and different way to use wifi.

The goal is for me to buy the best equipment and be able to use wireless without worrying at last.

I'm currently on Ubuntu 13.10 on a desktop pc with a Zyxel wireless dongle and it doesn't work good...

P.S. (sorry for my english :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have chosen my USB wireless adapter stick by cross checking the store USB stick with the list of tested USB stick from help.ubuntu :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Comment: Installed the Edimax EW-7711UAn on 13.10 (on a desktop). It works perfectly out-of-the-box !

Answer (score 1):

WiFi performance depends mostly on the chipset on your WiFi card (or stick) and the driver for said chipset. At the moment, the driver least likely to cause problems seems to be the **ath9k**.

The driver info page has a [list of all supported chipsets](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/products).

Usually, cards or sticks with one of those chipsets are easy (and cheap) to come by. Also, the newer models are capable of using both the **n** wireless standard and 5GHz frequencies, which makes them rather futureproof.

Comment: Thank you ! Which stick would you advise me to buy for my desktop pc ?

Comment: Any stick with the AR9374 chipset should do. It's hard to recommend a specific device without knowing where you want to buy it, but most decent shops include the chipset in the description.

Comment: OK Thx I will buy it ASAP and accept your answer once I have it working !

Comment: I can't find any stick with AR9374 chipset in the list of the driver info page.